# @ExampleObject description attribute not empty in Swagger online editor (produced by springdoc-openapi-ui 1.7.0)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I'm facing this issue that also if the ***description*** attribute for the ***@ExampleObject*** [(doc)](https://javadoc.io/doc/io.swagger.core.v3/swagger-annotations/2.1.4/io/swagger/v3/oas/annotations/media/ExampleObject.html) annotation is empty, in the swagger online editor it is show, and it takes the name of the example.

Here **my code**, where I define the api response for my endpoint:

```java
@ApiResponse(
    responseCode = "200", 
    description = "Book found", 
    content = { 
        @Content(
            mediaType = "application/json", 
            schema = @Schema(implementation = Book.class),
            examples = {
                @ExampleObject(
                    name = "example 1", 
                    value = "{\"id\": \"1\", \"title\":\"The Fellowship of the Ring\", \"author\": \"J.R.R. Tolkien\", \"publisher\": \"Allen & Unwin\"}"),
                @ExampleObject(
                    name = "example 2",
                    description = "",
                    value = "{\"id\": \"1\", \"title\":\"The Fellowship of the Ring\", \"author\": \"J.R.R. Tolkien\", \"publisher\": null}")})})
```

As you can see in the code snippet, the description is not set for the *example 1*, so I'm expecting the default value (""), and is set to an empty string in the *example 2*.

But when I connect to [swagger local editor](http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html) here is the result that I'll see for **example 1**
[image: example 1]

Also for the **example 2**
[image: example 2]

The editor will show me always the description, but I don't need it. I've tried to open an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/4448) but at the moment no one has answer it.

Also if I write the code in this way, the result doesn't change:

```java
@ApiResponses(value = {
    @ApiResponse(
        responseCode = "200", 
        description = "Book found", 
        content = { 
            @Content(
                mediaType = "application/json", 
                schema = @Schema(implementation = Book.class),
                examples = {
                    @ExampleObject(
                        name = "example 1", 
                        value = "{\"id\": \"1\", \"title\":\"The Fellowship of the Ring\", \"author\": \"J.R.R. Tolkien\", \"publisher\": \"Allen & Unwin\"}"),
                    @ExampleObject(
                        name = "example 2", 
                        value = "{\"id\": \"1\", \"title\":\"The Fellowship of the Ring\", \"author\": \"J.R.R. Tolkien\", \"publisher\": null}")})})
```

What do I have to do?

I'm using:

1. Java 8
2. Spring Boot 2.7.16
3. [springdoc-openapi-ui 1.7.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springdoc/springdoc-openapi-ui/1.7.0)